# next js 13 using app router next/dynamic import typescript error ''cannot be used as a JSX component''

Tags: typeerror, next.js13, typescript-eslint

I get an error type message like this. in my next js 13 using app router

```
Type error: 'SideContent' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{ exclude?: string | undefined; }, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<{ exclude?: string | undefined; }, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<{ exclude?: string | undefined; }, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/Github/stimi-yipmi-landing-page/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
              Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.

  74 |         </div>
  75 |         <div className='md:col-span-3'>
> 76 |           <SideContent />
     |            ^
  77 |         </div>
  78 |       </div>
  79 |     </Container>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

i got the above error when i made `<SideContent />` dynamic using `next/dynamic`. i want to remove typescript error `'SideContent' cannot be used as a JSX component.` in my component SideContent. so I can build my project

```
const SideContent = dynamic(() => import('src/components/Layout/SideContent'))
```

and this package.json

```
{
  "name": "stimi-yapmi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p  3002",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@trendyol-js/react-carousel": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/node": "20.1.4",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.6.0",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.7",
    "html-react-parser": "^4.0.0",
    "next": "^13.4.7",
    "next-nprogress-bar": "^2.0.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1",
    "swr": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.13.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of SideContent?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `next` to version `13.4.12` by doing:

`npm i next@13.4.12` in the terminal (or use `yarn`)

If this doesnt work, try deleting `node_modules` folder, the `lockfile` (package-lock.json or yarn.lock) and reinstall the dependencies

I would also recommend you to avoid installing `types` libraries as `dependencies`, instead install them as `devDependency` since you dont need them on production (its just for typing purposes when developing)

In example, uninstall and install `@types/react` as devDependency:

`npm uninstall @types/react && npm install --dev @types/react`

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper for your dynamic component, so you don't import next/dynamic inside your server component. And import this wrapper instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).